# Using conditionals within variable declaration

Tags: javascript, variables, conditional-statements

I'm trying to detect the "Do not track" setting on browsers... the origionla working code is:

```
if(navigator.doNotTrack == "yes" || navigator.doNotTrack == "1" || navigator.msDoNotTrack == "1"){
    alert("true");
}else{
    alert("false");
}
```

I'm trying to re-write it slightly and I'm wondering how to use a conditional within a variable declaration? I've come up with a not-working snippet that I was wondering if someone could help me with?

```
var DNT     = navigator.doNotTrack,
    msDNT   = navigator.msDoNotTrack,
    DNTtrue = "yes" || "1";

if(DNT === DNTtrue || msDNT === DNTtrue){
    alert("true");
}else{
    alert("false");
}
```

Comment: this `DNTtrue = "yes" || "1";` results to `true` due to javascript lose typing. which means this `DNT === DNTtrue` is equivalent to `DNT === true`

Comment: that's not true, `"yes" || "1"` results to `"yes"`

Comment: OK so how do I make it equal to "yes" or "1"??

Comment: what's wrong with the 1st condition?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it really, just like to re-write things to help improve my JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't to it like this. The expression `"yes" || "1"` is evaluated at the moment it is encountered. So you end up comparing `DNT` and `msDNT` to `"yes"`. There is no way to tell JS to evaluate an expression later instead. In even then, `DNT === "yes" || "1"` or `DNT === ("yes" || "1")` would not yield desired results either.

Here is an alternative solution, which simply tests whether the value of `DNT` or `msDNT` exists are property in an object:

```
var DNTtrue = {"yes": true, "1": true};

if (DNTtrue[DNT] || DNTtrue[msDNT]) {
    // ...    
}
```

If `DNT` or `msDNT` have a different value than `"yes"` and `"1"`, then `DNTtrue[...]` tries to access a non-existing property which will result in `undefined` (a falsy value).

Comment: Legend!! could you explain the inner working a little more? Will accept after 3 mins

Comment: Thanks, understand much better now, will definitely use this technique in the future

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers you could use an array and the `indexOf()` method:

```
DNTtrue = ["yes", "1"];

if(DNTtrue.indexOf(DNT) > -1 || DNTtrue.indexOf(msDNT) > -1){
    alert("true");
}else{
    alert("false");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try DNT.value inside if statement
Make DNTtrue=true not to yes